# Cross Domain IFRAME resize

Tags: html, iframe, cross-domain

I know this get's asked a lot, but how do I set the dynamic height of a cross domain iframe, when I don't have access to the actual page the IFRAME is showing?

Comment: javascript? http://stackoverflow.com/q/7651440

Comment: "I know this get's asked a lot" — so why are you asking it again?

Comment: Because even after trying the usual solutions, there's still an issue, so I was looking to see if anybody had any unique ideas.

Comment: may be we can help you solve the issue then..

Comment: Basically, it's an iframe inside an iframe, so for ease I will call them Page(the top window that the user access') Iframe1(is on the same domain as PAGE) Iframe2(on another domain that I do not have access to) Iv'e tried all the usual stuff, does anybody have ideas, I want to keep this dynamic as the height of iframe2 will change. Many thanks.

Comment: @Devon Barrett — What "usual" solutions? If you have an attempt, why isn't it in the question?

Comment: Solutions tried: 
   -Alertsize method on PAGE and Iframe1
   -$(window).height(); method
   -JQuery solution
   -even simple css '100%'

Comment: Whats the qoal? What is the "level of professionalism" you need? You could use a proxy or YQL to extract content from a page and insert that instead of Iframed content.

Comment: Professional site taking over 3000 hits daily. Proxies are no go's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. There is no way to know what the height of the document in the frame is from outside the frame because [all information about the document is protected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) from third party sites.

Comment: I thought that would be the case, but is there not anyway round it, even to compute the dimensions?

Comment: The only ways around it require the page on the other domain to cooperate. Since it isn't under your control, it won't.

Comment: No. You'd need the other side to run JS to send cross domain messages.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to add javascript on both parent and iframe page you can add this to both:

```
document.domain = 'mydomain.com';
```

This way you avoid the cross-domain restrictions, and can sniff the hight to change iframe height in parent page

Comment: Thanks but I don not have access to the page.

Comment: "when I don't have access to the actual page the IFRAME is showing" this was in his question.

Comment: @Shoban - "your so clever" - But just trying to help..... not being on the same domain dosen't rule our the vauge possibillity, that the provider of the iframe content wasn't willing to help out....

Comment: @Shoban :-) But yes, my answer only makes sense in certain cases, and I should have had a clear disclaimer - or just made it a comment. So I probably deserved that...

Answer (score 0):

have to proxy the page though your own server (at least one time)

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.megaupload.com'); 
echo $homepage;
?>
<script>etc</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue too but I finally got a solution:

Put this code inside the `<head>`:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  function resizeCrossDomainIframe(id, other_domain) {
    var iframe = document.getElementById(id);
    window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
      if (event.origin !== other_domain) return; // only accept messages from the specified domain
      if (isNaN(event.data)) return; // only accept something which can be parsed as a number
      var height = parseInt(event.data) + 0; // add some extra height to avoid scrollbar
      iframe.height = height + "px";
    }, false);
  };
</script>
```

Then, use this code for the iframe:

```
<iframe src='http://www.example.com/my-iframe/' frameborder="0" id="my_iframe" onload="resizeCrossDomainIframe('my_iframe', 'http://www.example.com');">
```